# Why are Apache Beam Transforms causing extra null elements in PCollection Window on GCP Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**For example**:

I am receiving and analyzing stream data in JSON format from GCP pub-sub, consisting of 320K unique messages. However, I encountered an issue with the duplication window, as it resulted in an additional 8.5K empty Messages.
The number of additional empty elements is not consistent

**How did I know there was an extra element?**

1. I am checking the value for each collection and writing it on logs so I can see all the non-empty 320K messages and the additional 8.5K empty messages.
2. Dataflow UI - refer to the attached image.

   [image]

**This is the code:**

```
Repeatedly triggerPersonWindow = Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane());

Window<KV<String, PubSubRelationsMessage>> personWindow = Window.<KV<String, PubSubRelationsMessage>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(10)))
                .triggering(triggerPersonWindow)
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                .discardingFiredPanes();


PCollectionTuple separateRelationMessages = parsedRelationMessages.get(ParseSplitPersonCompanyMessage.parsedRelationMessageTag)
                .apply("Person Window", personWindow)
                .apply("PS Deduplication", GroupByKey.create())
                .apply("Separate Messages", ParDo.of(new SeparateRelationMessages())
                        .withOutputTags(SeparateRelationMessages.updateDeleteFlowTag, TupleTagList.of(SeparateRelationMessages.addedTag).and(GlobalTupleTag.InputError).and(GlobalTupleTag.GeneralError)));
```

Apache Beam Version 2.37.0

Gradle 7.2

Java 17

**I attempted to:**

- Upgrading the versions of Apache Beam, Gradle, and Java.
- Reducing the number of DF workers to just one worker.

Unfortunately, nothing has helped solve the issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: This seems like an internal issue I would suggest opening an issue on GCP [issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or file a support case explaining the scenario.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what do you mean about "empty messages"? Are you looking at it after your GroupByKey?

Comment: @BrunoVolpato I am currently examining the code after GroupByKey. Occasionally, I encounter Null objects, although I am confident that no Null things exist with the Inputs. 
This issue does not occur when I run the code on my computer.
As SakshiGatyan said, it is an issue on GCP. However, at this time, we have decided not to proceed with that particular code.
Thanks